# POST request to my Node.js server returns 404 in production

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, axios

I am making a `POST` API request via Axios to my Node server to send a `string` value into my MongoDB.

The below code works well locally at `localhost:8080` but as soon as I push my code to Heroku, the requests start to return a `404`. My node server runs over `https` and I have configured CORS on its Express framework.

Here is the output I receive when I make the `POST` request to my node server:

> POST https://www.mynodeserverurl.com/api/upload-csv 404 (Not Found)

And here is my code for the Node server that processes this API request.

**NodeServer/app.js**

```
// Add headers so we can make API requests
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  // intercept OPTIONS method
  if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
    res.sendStatus(200);
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

**NodeServer/routes/api/api.js**

```
router.post('/upload-csv/', (req, res) => {
  let csv = req.body.csv_string.split('$');

  let csv_name = csv[0];
  let csv_string = csv_name+csv[1];

  CSVStore.findOne({url: csv_name})
    .then((csv) => {
      console.log('IN POST REQUEST');
      console.log(csv_string);

      return res.status(204).json({msg: 'All good!'});
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('There was an error!', err);

    });
});
```

Making a `POST` request to the above route doesn't even display the `console.log()` results in the Node server console.

Here is my code for the webapp that makes the `POST` request to the NodeServer

```
axios.post(`${utils.fetchURL()}/upload-csv`, {
    csv_string: csv_string
  })
  .then(function(response) {
    console.log('Response', response);
    return {};
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('There was an error!', error);
    return {};
  });
```

The URL I am making the `POST` request on is correct and `csv_string` is not empty; it has data.

Is there some kind of configuration I need to make in my NodeServer's `app.js` to allow CORS on `https`?

**UPDATE:** I can confirm that a `GET` request works. I am able to make a `GET` request to retrieve a `string` from my MongoDB. Why does `GET` work and `POST` does not?

Comment: if `axios.post(\`${utils.fetchURL()}/upload-csv\`, {` really does `axios.post(\`https://www.mynodeserverurl.com/api/upload-csv\`, {` and the `/api/upload-csv` path in that URL *somehow* is translated to `/upload-csv` - then there's nothing wrong with your code that you've posted

Comment: Yes it all looks correct (I think) but I ONLY get the 404 error in production not locally. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: I can't see how `router.post('/upload-csv/'` would handle a call to `/api/upload-csv` ... see tha `api` in there?

Comment: Because in my `app.js` file on my Node Server, I define my routes and the extensions. So since `routes/api/api.js` returns an objects with my routes defined, I could `import` my API routes in `app.js` and use `app.use('/api', api);`

Comment: OK, I don't know enough about `routes` to understand any of that :p - I take it on localhost you `http://localhost:8080/api/upload-csv` without issue

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same problem. All my API endpoints worked locally and in prod, but my one POST endpoint would 404 in production, but worked for a GET.

It turned out that before running "git push heroku master" I had forgot to stage and commit my most recent changes. Once I did that and ran "git push heroku master" again, everything was published and working in production.

So try that if you're having this issue